# Can a sass @mixin accept an undefined number of arguments?

Tags: undefined, sass, arguments, mixins

I'm trying to create a sass mixin for transitions. This is what I have so far.

```
@mixin transition($var)
  -webkit-transition: $var
  transition: $var
```

I want to be able to pass it multiple arguments like this

```
@include transition(color .5s linear, width .5s linear)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error

```
Syntax error: Mixin transition takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.
```

Is there a way to do this so it produces the following output in css while still accepting an undefined number of arguments?

```
-webkit-transition: color .5s linear, width .5s linear;
transition: color .5s linear, width .5s linear;
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Variable Arguments**

Sometimes it makes sense for a mixin to take an unknown number of arguments. For example, a mixin for creating box shadows might take any number of shadows as arguments. For these situations, Sass supports “variable arguments,” which are arguments at the end of a mixin declaration that take all leftover arguments and package them up as a list. These arguments look just like normal arguments, but are followed by `...`. For example:

```css
@mixin box-shadow($shadows...) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
}

.shadows {
  @include box-shadow(0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999);
}
```

is compiled to:

```css
.shadows {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999;
}
```

From : [SASS official Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments)

So you basically just need to change your mixins declaration to look like this :

```css
@mixin transition($var...)
  -webkit-transition: $var
  transition: $var
```

Comment: @troelskn I posted my answer way after Joseph's and his was already selected as THE answer. I added mine because I asked the very same question and found the answer in SASS Documentation and hoped it could save some devs the trouble of dealing with superfluous parentheses :)

Comment: Yes, it looks like this option was added in 2012, after the question and my answer were given. http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released/

Answer (score 37):

When you call the mixin, call it like this:

```
@include transition( (color .5s linear, width .5s linear) );
```

With the extra parens. This will key sass into the fact that you want this used as a single argument.

**EDIT**: See Jeremie Parker's answer above if using Sass 3.2 or later. Real Variable Arguments were added in 3.2: http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released

Comment: So is that a single list value now?

Answer (score 3):

In case you want **multiple arguments** and **vendor-prefixed**, like the fallowing scenario:

```
@include transition(transform .5s linear, width .5s linear)
```

**Expected**

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
transition: transform 0.5s linear, width 0.5s linear;
```

I suggest you this **Mixin**, I found on [Meaningless Writing](http://log.vieron.net/articles/sass-mixins-for-vendor-prefixed-transitions-including-properties/).
**Code**

```
@function prefix($property, $prefixes: (webkit moz o ms)) {
    $vendor-prefixed-properties: transform background-clip background-size;
    $result: ();
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
       @if index($vendor-prefixed-properties, $property) {
         $property: -#{$prefix}-#{$property}
       }
       $result: append($result, $property);
    }
    @return $result;
}

@function trans-prefix($transition, $prefix: moz) {
    $prefixed: ();
    @each $trans in $transition {
        $prop-name: nth($trans, 1);
        $vendor-prop-name: prefix($prop-name, $prefix);
        $prop-vals: nth($trans, 2);
        $prefixed: append($prefixed, ($vendor-prop-name $prop-vals), comma);
    }

    @return $prefixed;
}

@mixin transition($values...) { 
    $transitions: ();
    @each $declaration in $values {
        $prop: nth($declaration, 1);
        $prop-opts: ();
        $length: length($declaration);
        @for $i from 2 through $length {
            $prop-opts: append($prop-opts, nth($declaration, $i));   
        }
        $trans: ($prop, $prop-opts);
        $transitions: append($transitions, $trans, comma);
    }

    -webkit-transition: trans-prefix($transitions, webkit);
    -moz-transition: trans-prefix($transitions, moz);
    -o-transition: trans-prefix($transitions, o);
    transition: $values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compass has a transition mixin that you could take a look at (or you could just use Compass). You can take a better look at it here: http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/.

By the looks of it you can't do an undefined number of mixins as the maintainer of Compass also aids in maintaining Sass and you can see that he has defined a maximum number of 10 separate arguments for his transition mixin.