# Sass mixin with multiple optional parameters, but only one property

Tags: css, sass

So I'm trying to do something functionally equivalent to this:

[Can a sass @mixin accept an undefined number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895796/can-a-sass-mixin-accept-an-undefined-number-of-arguments)

...with a `transitionFast` mixin, but I want to be strict about the easing functions and speeds, so I've defined them within the mixin, like so:

```
@mixin transitionFast($property) {
    -webkit-transition:$property ease 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:$property ease 0.2s;
    -o-transition:$property ease 0.2s;
    transition:$property ease 0.2s;
}
```

How can I pass multiple `$properties` to this, without passing through the `ease 0.2s` part? I've tried this:

```
@mixin transitionFast($properties...) {
    @each $property in $properties {
        transition:$property ease 0.5s;
    }
}
```

which I'm trying to call like this:

```
@include transitionFast(background-color, color);
```

but it doesn't work and only applies the transition to the last passed argument. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In your case there are several ways to go with sass splat-like args:

**1)** If you define mixin with splat args like so:

```
@mixin transitionFast($properties...) { 
  # with iteration on $properties
}
```

And you include it normal like this:

```
@include transitionFast(firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg);
```

Then you get

```
# compiled
transition: firstArg;
transition: secondArg;
transition: thirdArg;
```

**2)** You will also get the same thing when you don't specify splat args

```
@mixin transitionFast($properties) { 
  # with iteration on $properties
}
```

And include them with double parents

```
@include transitionFast((firstArg, secondArg, thirdArg));
```

**3)** If you declare mixin this way:

```
@mixin transitionFast($properties...) { 
  # with iteration on $properties
}
```

and call it whis way:

```
@include transitionFast(( background-color, color, red ));
```

you will get behavior similar to default behavior (ie without iteration over splat):

```
transition: background-color, color, red;
```

Now, back to your question, you can do this to get what You want:

```
$ease: ease 0.5s;
@mixin transitionFast($properties...) {    
    @each $prop in $properties {
        transition: $prop $ease;
    }
}
html {
  @include transitionFast( background-color, color, margin );
}
```

Edit: instead `transition: $prop $ease;` go with compass `@include transition( $prop $ease );` as Pik_at suggested, its more dry and sexy.

**Just for fun:**

If you leave (above) mixin as it is and include it like this:

```
@include transitionFast(( background-color, color ), padding);
```

it compiles to

```
transition: background-color, color ease 0.5s;
transition: padding ease 0.5s;
```

combining iteration and regular 'splatting', very cool stuff :)

Comment: Great breakdown, I can't believe this hasn't received an upvote +1

Answer (score 0):

Array parameters should be on bracket like:

```
@include transitionFast((background-color, color));
```

I made a simple code test to show you:
http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/wBjgpY

Likewise, using Compass would help you to add transition mixin with browsers prefix:

```
@mixin transitionFast($properties) {
    @each $property in $properties {
        @include transition($property 2s ease);
    }
}
```